# React - Import module from wrong path

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, import

I'm developing a library of components for my projects in React, but I had some problem with it. 
I have published the library in NPM, the problem is that, after installing the library, I try to import as other components

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { DatePickerCustom, UploadFile } from 'splibkoare';
import { Greetings } from 'library-test-core-react'

const DatePicker = () => {

console.log(Greetings)

return (
    <Fragment>
        < DatePickerCustom />
        <UploadFile />
    </Fragment>
)
}
export default DatePicker
```

When compiling, it tries to import the file from a wrong path

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Failed to compile.

./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'library-test-core-react' in C:\Repos\myComponents\my_components\src\myComponent|views'
```

I don't know if it is an error in the webpack config or what. Can anyone please help me? Cheers.

EDIT: I fixed it with the good old method "turn it off, then turn it on again"

Comment: Please post your code and error messages as **text** - linked images are not really that useful.

Comment: It sounds like your webpack.config might be misconfigured, specifically [`resolve.modules`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvemodules) which governs which directories to search in.

Comment: Well probably need to see your webpack.config before we'll be able to start diagnosing the issue.

Comment: I fixed it with the good old method "turn it off, then turn it on again"